# How to install a specific version of GCC in Kali Linux?

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, gcc, dpkg, aptitude

This question appears to be addressed properly in several questions and other
places easily found with Google, but I don't find the solution satisfactory
for the reasons explained below. But just for completion, I've included some
relevant links:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get
https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package/428778
https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version
...

And others.

However, this question is regarding installing a very specific version of GCC in Kali Linux, which does not appear readily available as a specific package. In particular, the question is regarding how to install version 6.3.0, as I need this version to compile a particular program: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6d0ah8/xmrig_miner_new_release/

(as a bonus question, if there is a more sane way to fix this particular
issue without using a different version of GCC, feel free to answer, but I believe this question is general and I would like to know how to do it regardless of how to make the aforementioned program link correctly)

The versions which are available to install of any package, e.g. gcc, can be
determined with:

```
apt-cache showpkg gcc
```

Which will list the available versions under "versions:", e.g.

```
4:7.2.0-1d1
4:4.9.2-2
```

Installation is then as simple as issuing

```
apt-get install gcc:4:4.9.2-2
```

This will install the older version 4:4.9.2-2, by simply (I believe)
overwriting the 7.2.0-1d1 install, if present.

To get version 4:4.9.2-2 available at all, I had to add `deb
http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib` to my
`/etc/apt/sources.list` file and then run `apt-get update`.

However, what if the version I need is not listed?

I've been experimenting with various sources, e.g. those found here:
http://snapshot.debian.org/ and at various other questions and websites from Google searches.

Most of them give me ignore or errors, e.g. as follows

```
Ign:3 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20091004T111800Z lenny InRelease
```

Even if this would work, it seems to be a very bad approach to get a
particular version installed, as adding some arbitrary source might not have the particular version I want.

If I search on snapshot.debian.org for gcc, I get only very old versions: http://snapshot.debian.org/package/gcc/

I eventually became frustrated with this approach and compiled GCC 6.3.0 from the source tarball. The compilation was successful, but then I'm faced with how to install it. I'm cautious about running `make install` as I fear it will tamper with `apt` and `dpkg` and possibly break the system.

Instead, I attempted to run it from the build directory, directly. I tried to simply add the build directory as the first entry in my PATH, which didn't work. Then, I attempted to rename `/usr/bin/gcc` and do a symlink from `/usr/bin/gcc` to where my gcc-6.3.0 executable lives. This presents the following problem:

```
cc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory, which
```

This was fixed with another entry in my PATH.

Then, I get this error:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:34:21: fatal error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
```

Which I assume is because of a missing entry in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu`. I tried to make a symlink from 6 to 6.3.0, but this wasn't sufficient. I also tried to actually copy everything with `cp -R`, same result.

This should be a 64-bit program, but I also considered the same for
`/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu`.

I'm sure I could start doing `strace` to see where it attempts to open the files from, read log files, read the source, and eventually I imagine I'd be able to figure out how to hack together a poorly conceived solution. But it would be nice if someone could tell me how to do this in a sane manner.

Comment: This doesn’t detract from the general merits of your question; but current [releases](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/releases) of [XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) should build fine with GCC 7, so you should just be able to build it without messing around with GCC 6.3.

Comment: You can always compile GCC (any not too ancient version) from its [source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html), since it is free software. Be careful when configuring it, and build it outside of its source tree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to install a specific version of GCC in Kali Linux?

GCC 6 is available on kali linux it can be installed as follow :

```
apt install g++-6 gcc-6
```

To switch between gcc6 and gcc7

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 1 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 2 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6
update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Sample output:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gcc-6   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gcc-6   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gcc-7   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Select your default `gcc` version.

on 2017-08-05 the gcc-6 version is upgraded from `6.3.0` to `6.4.0` .

> Installing `xmrig` following the [build's](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/wiki/Ubuntu-Build) instructions.

```
apt-get install git build-essential cmake libuv1-dev libmicrohttpd-dev
git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git
cd xmrig
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

**Building a specific gcc version `6.3.0`**

Download the tarball from the closest [mirror](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) :  [GCC Releases](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html)

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
cd gcc-6.3.0
apt build-dep gcc
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-6.3.0/configure --prefix=/usr/bin/gcc-6.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go --disable-multilib
make -j 8
make install
```

Add `gcc-6.3` to `update-alternatives`

**Important** : The `--disable-multilib` option is required to configure and build `gcc` for the current architecture.

[GCC WIKI : Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC)

Comment: Forgive me, but doesn't this install whatever version of GCC that "gcc-6" provides? What if I want to install specifically 6.3.0?

Comment: @AlphaCentauri 6 months ago the available gcc6 version is `6.3.0` , now the gcc6 version is upgraded to `6.4.0` .

Comment: @AlphaCentauri  answer updated including the building steps.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to go to this website : http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html
2. Then select old-releases and you will see different versions.
3. Now you should click in the one that you want to have and the download will start.
4. Finally, you have to compile and install from source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe you've read my whole question. I pointed out how I have attempted to compile from source. The problem with this (as pointed out in my question), is that doing "make install" on GCC might not be a good idea as it might possibly break the system. Furthermore, simply running GCC without doing make install introduces its own challenges, which I've also outlined in my original question.

Comment: You have stated in your question that `make install` might tamper with `dpkg` or `apt`.. can you elaborate! @AlphaCentauri

Answer (score 0):

If you did a standard `./configure; make` without passing any options to `configure`, then `make install` will place the pieces of your desired version of GCC in various subdirectories of `/usr/local`.

The `/usr/local` directory tree is intended for software installed by the system administrator outside of the package-management system (ie. exactly what you're doing).  As such, software installed there will not break packaged software except in extremely unusual circumstances.

GCC in particular is designed around the assumption that you'll have multiple versions installed.  It pretty much requires active measures on your part to break anything (eg. by mixing and matching pieces to try to create a hybrid version).

Comment: You should not (and probably won't succeed in) building GCC in its source tree. And you probably want additional options to its `configure` script (e.g. some `-program-suffix=` etc)

Answer (score 0):

> I eventually became frustrated with this approach and compiled GCC 6.3.0 from the source tarball. The compilation was successful,

First, I would recommend, if you compile GCC from its source, to choose a more recent version (e.g. [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) at end of 2017).

Then, be sure to build GCC *outside* of its source tree and to try first its `configure` script with `--help` and to **pass more options to its `configure`**. Read *carefully* the [GCC installation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) instructions and understand the role of [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf).

In practice, I recommend

- run `/usr/bin/gcc -v` to understand how your system's GCC has been configured
- run `apt-get build-dep gcc-6` (or similar) to get recent system's GCC dependencies
- create a build directory outside of your GCC source tree, and run further `.../configure` (replace `...` by appropriate relative path, e.g. `../gcc-7.2/`) and `make` there.
- you probably want to pass at least `--program-suffix=-mine` to that `configure` (the `-mine` can be replaced by another suffix) and you might even add `--prefix=$HOME/soft/` if you don't have root access. You'll probably want *additional options* to `configure` and you need to choose and give them carefully.
- then a later `make install` (you could even run without being root `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/gccinst/` and later copy carefully and recursively as root that `/tmp/gccinst/` ....) would install things in `/usr/local/bin/gcc-mine` etc.... (or `$HOME/soft/bin/gcc-mine` ....) so won't break any system installed files.

Notice that the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) requires the package management system to leave alone `/usr/local/` (which is the default `--prefix` for GCC's `configure`)

Comment: The OP already *has* GCC 7, but was looking for 6.3.0 following a misguided reddit comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a precompiled 
[toolchain](https://toolchains.bootlin.com) or this one for your
[specific](https://toolchains.bootlin.com/downloads/releases/toolchains/x86-64-core-i7/tarballs/x86-64-core-i7--glibc--bleeding-edge-2017.05-toolchains-1-2.tar.bz2) architecture (x86_64, glibc, gcc 6.3).

Of course next option is to use a so called rootfs-builder like 
buildroot or yocto
to generate a toolchain with your specfic gcc version.